# Should the name attribute of the meta tag be "description" or "meta-description"?

Tags: wordpress, meta-tags, meta-description

Can anyone tell me what the difference between `description` and `meta-description`?

I've just read on the WordPress blog to mainly use "meta-description" as it's strongly recommended.  I'm confused.

```
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="meta-description" content="">
```

Comment: Can you give a link to this blog post you read?  It doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller thank you for the input. Actually this is an advice from SEO expert, i ll ask him any website link that explaining this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"meta-description" is a notation that means: [`meta`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element) element with the [`description`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/document-metadata.html#description) name. (I’m using it for example [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29648304/1591669).)

So you don’t use `meta-description` as name (which would be invalid anyway, because it’s [not registered](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions)), but `description`.